# Python Requests And Flask server exe trouble

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, exe

I'm using a flask server in python. When I POST an exe with the requests library then write the file as `client.exe` the file corrupts.

I tried and double checked that I was using the read / write `binary` functions and I was. I don't know what to try now.

Code that sends the info:
`

```
import requests, shutil
targeturl = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/latest"

with open("client_copy.exe", "rb") as f:
    files = {
        "file": f.read()
    } 
    response = requests.post(targeturl, files)
    shutil.copyfile("client_copy.exe", "client.exe")
print(f"Request Sent. Response code: {response.status_code}. {response.reason}")
```

Flask Server Code:

```
@app.route("/latest", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def latest():
    if request.method == "GET":
        path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "client.exe")
        return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        with open("client.exe", "wb") as file:
            file.write(request.form["file"].encode("utf-8"))
        return "Success", 200
    else:
        return print(f"Error: {request.method} is not a valid method. Use GET or POST. Error code: {request.status_code}.")
```

**The server works by itself. The issue is with the exe that it writes.

Comment: Maybe you do not need `encode("utf-8")` in the call of `file.write`.

Comment: tried that. did not work.